# how to convert ncdf4 to data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ncdf4

I want use the function "filled.contour", but my data file are ncdf4 file.

how to convert ncdf4 file to data.frame in R?

Some advice?

thanks

Comment: Hi Ana, welcome to StackOverflow. Please can you post what you have tried and found so far? A quick Google suggests there is some information available on this http://geog.uoregon.edu/bartlein/courses/geog490/week04-netCDF.html does that cover your use case?

Comment: See also [`rasterVis`](https://oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis/)

Answer (score 1):

Because a NetCDF file can contain objects of many different dimensions, it is not a straightforward conversion. If you know the names of the variable you want to get out of the file you can do it like this:

`library(ncdf4)
nc<-nc_open("filename")
ncvar_get(nc,varid= "variableNameInFile" )
nc_close(nc)`

If you dont know the names of the attributes in your file you can use this to obtain them:

`library(ncdf4)
nc<-nc_open("filename")
var.idNames<-names(nc$var)
nc_close(nc)`

Once you extract the individual variables you can just put them into a dataframe (data.frame()) if they are the same dimensions.

Hope this Helps!
(and don't forget to close your file when you're done)